# NVDA - Screen reader doesn't announce ListView Items

Tags: wpf, accessibility, nvda

I have a WPF App with a ListView control to show a list of errors. When I clear and add items to the ListView the Windows narrator will announce them but NVDA reader doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewAccessibility.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewAccessibility"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="errorsListView" Margin="28,0,0,0"
            Height="150"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ErrorItems}"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Errors"
            AutomationProperties.LiveSetting="Assertive"
            >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <WrapPanel >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorText}" FontWeight="Bold"  
                               AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ErrorText}" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button Command="{Binding AddErrorCommand}">Add Item</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)errorsListView.Items).CollectionChanged += ListViewCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void ListViewCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (errorsListView.Items?.Count > 0)
        {
            RaiseListViewLiveRegionChanged();
        }
    }

    private void RaiseListViewLiveRegionChanged()
    {
        var peer = UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(errorsListView);
        if (peer == null)
        {
            peer = UIElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(errorsListView);
        }
        peer.RaiseAutomationEvent(AutomationEvents.LiveRegionChanged);
    }
}




public class ErrorInfo
{
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
}
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ErrorInfo> ErrorItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ErrorInfo>();

    private ICommand _addErrorCommand;
    public ICommand AddErrorCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _addErrorCommand ?? (_addErrorCommand = new RelayCommand(() => AddError()));
        }
    }

    int idx = 0;
    private void AddError()
    {
        ErrorItems.Clear();
        ErrorItems.Add(new ErrorInfo() { ErrorText = $"New Error {idx++}" });
    }
}
```

Inspect.exe result

[image]

Comment: Try using [microsoft's accessibility inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) (inspect.exe) to see what the role of the element is.

Comment: Added a screenshot from inspect.exe

Answer (score 0):

It seems `UiaRaiseNotificationEvent` is a solution:

```
    public enum AutomationNotificationKind
    {
        ItemAdded = 0,
        ItemRemoved = 1,
        ActionCompleted = 2,
        ActionAborted = 3,
        Other = 4
    }

    public enum AutomationNotificationProcessing
    {
        ImportantAll = 0,
        ImportantMostRecent = 1,
        All = 2,
        MostRecent = 3,
        CurrentThenMostRecent = 4
    }
    public class AccessabilityUtils
    {
        private const string UIAutomationCore = "UIAutomationCore.dll";
        [DllImport(UIAutomationCore, EntryPoint = "UiaRaiseNotificationEvent", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int RawUiaRaiseNotificationEvent(IRawElementProviderSimple provider, AutomationNotificationKind notificationKind, AutomationNotificationProcessing notificationProcessing, string displayString, string activityId);

        public static void UiaRaiseNotificationEvent(UIElement element, AutomationNotificationKind kind, AutomationNotificationProcessing processing, string message, string activityId)
        {
            if (element is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(element));
            }

            try
            {
                AutomationPeer peer = UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(element);
                if (peer == null)
                {
                    peer = UIElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(element);
                }

                MethodInfo pfpMethod = peer.GetType().GetMethod("ProviderFromPeer", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (pfpMethod == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                IRawElementProviderSimple provider = pfpMethod.Invoke(peer, new[] { peer }) as IRawElementProviderSimple;
                if (provider == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                message = $"{peer.GetName()} \n {message}";
                int hr = RawUiaRaiseNotificationEvent(provider, kind, processing, message, activityId);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                
            }
        }

    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)errorsListView.Items).CollectionChanged += ListViewCollectionChanged;
        }

        private void ListViewCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (errorsListView.Items?.Count > 0)
            {
                AccessabilityUtils.UiaRaiseNotificationEvent(errorsListView, AutomationNotificationKind.ActionCompleted,
                            AutomationNotificationProcessing.ImportantMostRecent, GetErrorMessage(errorsListView.Items), null);
            }
        }

        private string GetErrorMessage(ItemCollection items)
        {
            if (items == null)
                return string.Empty;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                sb.Append((item as ErrorInfo)?.ErrorText);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```